# Passing multiple values from all fragments to its container activity by onClick event

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can I get multiple editText value from all fragments by onClick event which located in its container activity? Those EditText are being valid and checking by TextWatcher. I can't get any value of editText by implementing inflate and return fragment's layout to its contain activity.

What is more, how can I handle the situation of passing editTexts' value when all editTexts are valid if using Interface on fragment.

Thanks for any help.

[image: Get editText from all fragment by onClick event in its container activity]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is several ways

1. Use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) where you save all the value first and
   then retrieve it later in activity.
2. Use interface class as bridge communication between fragment and activity 
   For Example:[example interface class](http://pastebin.com/zYqKrNi8)

Comment: I would like to use Interface class but how can I passed editTexts' value when all editTexts are valid, can I implement on onResume()?

Comment: just validate all the edittext value before submit first.. after all is true, just execute the bridge function, and the activity will immediately get the values. i believe activity not triggering the onResume() after fragment is close.

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner of coding android. I will find more about that. :)